# IIS Rewrite + Vue history mode making Windows Authentication not work

Tags: vue.js, iis, url-rewrite-module

I'm creating a Vue webpage with history mode hosted on IIS. I use URL Rewrite to route any path that doesn't resolve to a static file to my `index.html` file, like many [many forums](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-router-navigation-in-iis/6892/3) suggested, and the Vue does client side routing from there.

However, I'm also using Windows Authentication, and any time I go to a Vue route (that doesn't match a static file) in my browser (tested on multiple), it asks for my credentials and I enter the correct ones, but it just keeps asking me again and again for my credentials, without ever letting me in. On the other hand, when I route to a static file, I log in, and it lets me in just fine and I can then go to a Vue route because I'm already logged in.

Why is IIS URL Rewrite making my authentication repeat itself and not let me in? We've been at a bit of a loss and have had to route to static file first every time to log in.

The only thing I've found is to turn off Anonymous Authentication, and it is.

Here is my web.config with the rerouting instructions:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/Dashboard/vue/dist/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

(It reroutes to `/Dashboard/vue/dist/` because that contains an `index.html`)

Thanks!

Comment: IIS URL Rewrite can‘t retrieve the Windows login user information because IIS URL Rewrite gets executed before the Authentication Model in IIS process.

Comment: @samwu so what does that mean? Does the authenication get lost in the rerouting?

Comment: I mean when windows authentication happened, the url rewrite you are using hasn't happened.